# how can i send a list of p:selectOneRadio data to my managedbean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I´ve a dynamic list of p:selectOneRadio, that goes like this:

```
1 op1   op2   op3
2 op1   op2   op3
3 op1   op2   op3
```

So when I make my submit I want to know which option was chosen for row 1, and which option was chosen for row 2 and which option was chosen for row 3.
The problem I´ve is that I only get the last chosen option.
Here is my xhtml:

```
<ui:repeat var="o" value="#{perfilesMB.numbers}" varStatus="status">
    <p:selectOneRadio value="#{perfilesMB.number}">
        <p:ajax listener="#{perfilesMB.handleCityChange}" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>                                                     
</ui:repeat>
```

and here is my managed bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;  

@ManagedBean(name="perfilesMB")
//@RequestScoped 
@SessionScoped
public class PerfilesManagedBean implements Serializable{
    private List<String> numbers;
    private String number;

    public List<String> getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public void setNumbers(List<String> numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }


    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    //private String nivel;
    //private int id_seccion;

    public PerfilesManagedBean() {
        niveles = new ArrayList<String>();
        numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            numbers.add("" + i); 
        }
    }

    public String sendData(){
        System.out.println("Number: " + number);
        return "";
    }       

}
```

How can I fix it??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is this line:

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{perfilesMB.number}">
```

You are essentially binding all of your 3 selection items to a single bean property, under which the last request parameter sent is in fact the last one to end up, and overwrite, the bean property. You thus need to bind it to a corresponding element of an array, or a list, of numbers, like in

```
<ui:repeat ... varStatus="status">
    <p:selectOneRadio value="#{perfilesMB.numberSelection[status.index]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

with a backing

```
List<String> numberSelection;//initialized and equal to the amount of items in your UIRepeat component, i.e. with 3 empty strings added
```

Comment: Why not `value="#{perfilesMB.numbers[status.index]}"`?

Comment: @BalusC Because it seemed from OP's question, especially from bean constructor, that this list is supposed to be used for options, i.e. for the possible `<f:selectItems>` that were instead hardcoded.